# How to center align the text in Vaadin TextField

Tags: vaadin

I read the CSS styling section (https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/styling-components) and it mentions that global CSS doesnt affect the 'INPUT" field in the shadow DOM, So styling has to be added to shdaow DOM, But unfortunately no where does it explicitly say **HOW** to add the styling to the shadow DOM. Note. im using mainly Flow pure java with a  bit of CSS.

I tried retrieving the elementt from component then retrieving the shadowRoot, then from root, retrieve the 'input' element to add styling to it, unfortunately that didnt work, shadowroot was null (this code executed from the onAttach() method in the view class)

```
private void setTextAlignCenterForTextFields(TextField textField) {
        //find the internal 'Input' and set the styling to text-align=center, unfortunately
        // you cant do that with global css, since the 'input' element is in shadow root
        textField.getElement()
                .getShadowRoot()
                .get()
                .getChildren()
                .filter( elem -> "INPUT".equalsIgnoreCase(elem.getTag()))
                .forEach(inputElem -> inputElem.getStyle().set("text-align", "center"));
    }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. I'm using Vaadin version 14.5.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS to target the `value` part:

```css
.textfieldClass::part(value) {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This video explains styling CSS parts: https://youtu.be/Y0uxb4ga44Y

Answer (score 8):

There's already a theme variant to align the text

```java
centerTextField.addThemeVariants(TextFieldVariant.LUMO_ALIGN_CENTER);
```

see https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-text-field/java-examples/theme-variants

---

As for how to attach CSS to shadow root, basically use `themeFor`, see https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/importing-style-sheets/#component-styles

Comment: Here’s the link to the the most up-to-date docs: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/text-field/#text-alignment